# Java 8 stream filtering: IN clause

Tags: java, lambda

```
List<Y> tmp= new DATA<Y>().findEntities();
List<X> tmp1 = new DATA<X>().findEntities().stream().filter(
                        IN (tmp) ???
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to simulate a tipical IN clause (like in mysql or JPA) using a Predicate ?

Comment: `tmp.contains(entity)` where `tmp` is a `HashSet`.

Comment: `tmp::contains` (a method reference)

Comment: Can i have a Predicate (Implemented) example ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to update my comment to an answer. The lambda expression for your requested `Predicate<Y>` (where Y should be a concrete type) looks as following:

```
element -> tmp.contains(element)
```

Because the collection's `contains` method has the same signature as the predicate's `test` method, you can use a *method reference* (here an instance method reference):

```
tmp::contains
```

A full example:

```
List<Number> tmp = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> tmp1 = Arrays
    .stream(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
    .filter(tmp::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(tmp1);
```

This prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This generates a suspicious call to java.util.Collection.contains (sometimes)

Comment: I do not get a _suspicious call_ nor a compiler warning. I simply get the described output.