# How to use java stream to filter object?

Tags: java

How to use the filter in java to filter the complete object.
I am having an ArrayList that contains `name` and `amount`, I have another array of string that contains some string.

Now here how to filter and create a new ArrayList which contain only these two object which has `arr` elements.

I tried to use two methods `.equals` and `.contains` but it does not produce output.

```
List<Person> people = new ArayList<>();
people.add(new Person("Warren Buffett" , 90));
people.add(new Person("Jeff Bezos" , 180));
people.add(new Person("Bill Gates" , 140));
people.add(new Person("Mark" , 120));

String arr[]={"Mark" , "Bill Gates"};

List<Person> newPeople = people.stream().filter(person -> person.name.equals(arr))
List<Person> newPeople = people.stream().filter(person -> person.name.contains(arr)).collect(collectors.toList());

newPeople.forEach(person -> System.out.println(person.name));
```

Edit:

I should get the output as an array of an object that should contain Mark and Bill gates name and their amount

Comment: Err, so you know how to put elements into a list, but you want to keep your names in an array ... why? Why not use another List, and do namesList.contains()??? Also note that your example wouldnt even compile. So readers are wondering: "does the OP not know how to collect after filtering, and do we need to explain that" ... and so on. So please: make sure your code is "complete" and doesnt raise other questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 stream filtering: IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161830/java-8-stream-filtering-in-clause)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So you want a new list containing only the Person instancences which names appears in arr? Try do this:

```
List<Person> newPeople = people.stream()
    .filter(person -> arr.contains(person.name))
    .collect(collectors.toList());
```

The lambda variable "person" is referring to a single object contained in the people list, not to the list itself. So when you use person.name.equals(...) or person.name.contains(...) your are calling those methods on a string. Doing the reverse, as in my example, will give you the desired result; if not, let know and we'll dig dipper

edit:

I was assuming arr was a List, so before using my code you should consider to do te following

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

And then

```
List<Person> newPeople = people.stream()
.filter(person -> names.contains(person.name))
.collect(collectors.toList());
```

Assuming you're having that array passed by something else, if you're creating it you could just create a list and skipping the array "step"

Comment: `arr` is of type `String[]`, it has no `contains` method

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no `contains()` method for a `String` array. Does your code compile?

Comment: Try executing or at least compile the code you post!

Comment: omg you're right, i assumed it was a List, my fault

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find working solution. Use streams to iterate by your args array to find first matching arg.

```
List<Person> newPeople = people.stream()
            .filter(person -> Stream.of(arr).anyMatch(s -> person.name.equals(s)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());



newPeople.forEach(person -> System.out.println(person.name));
// Bill Gates
// Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this `person.name.contains(arr)`, rather you should be doing `person.name.contains(arr[0])` OR `person.name.contains(arr[1])`.
In order to do so, you might want to do nested iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to a list; then use the `List.contains()` to check if the `person.name` is available in that `list`.

First convert the array.

```
String arr[]={"Mark" , "Bill Gates"};
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Now, use the `List.contains()`

```
List<Person> newPeople 
   = people.stream().filter(
                             person -> names.contains(person.name)).collect(Collectors.toList()
                           );
```

Below is the full method after the update.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new Person("Warren Buffett" , 90));
    people.add(new Person("Jeff Bezos" , 180));
    people.add(new Person("Bill Gates" , 140));
    people.add(new Person("Mark" , 120));

    String arr[]={"Mark" , "Bill Gates"};
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList(arr);

    List<Person> newPeople = people.stream().filter(person -> names.contains(person.name)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    newPeople.forEach(person -> System.out.println(person.name));

}
```